# Message card rendering issue in bot framework v3

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a message card payload pushed from service now which is not rendering properly on MS Teams through bot framework. It only displays the content but not the button.Below is the payload, pls suggest what could be the issue.

BotFramework:V3
.Net SDK
Bot Builder package:3.12.2.4
Bot Connector:3.12.2.4
Bot.Connector.Teams:0.9.0

```
{
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.o365connector",
  "content": {
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "title": "Incident Updated - INC0010010",
    "summary": "Incident Updated - INC0010010",
    "themeColor": "D1222B",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "",
        "text": "",
        "activityTitle": "",
        "activitySubtitle": "",
        "activityText": "",
        "facts": [
          {
            "name": "Category",
            "value": "Software"
          },
          {
            "name": "State",
            "value": "New"
          },
          {
            "name": "Priority",
            "value": "5 - Planning"
          },
          {
            "name": "Assignment group",
            "value": "Software"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "Please check the details"
      }
    ],
    "potentialAction": [
      {
        "@type": "OpenUri",
        "name": "View Incident in ServiceNow",
        "targets": [
          {
            "os": "default",
            "uri": "https://dev62584.service-now.com/incident.do?sys_id=XXXXXXX&sysparm_stack=incident_list.do?sysparm_query=active=true"
          },
          {
            "os": "iOS",
            "uri": "https://dev62584.service-now.com/incident.do?sys_id=XXXXXXX&sysparm_stack=incident_list.do?sysparm_query=active=true"
          },
          {
            "os": "android",
            "uri": "https://dev62584.service-now.com/incident.do?sys_id=XXXXXXX&sysparm_stack=incident_list.do?sysparm_query=active=true"
          },
          {
            "os": "windows",
            "uri": "https://dev62584.service-now.com/incident.do?sys_id=7ec9865adb711010fcff8809489619b4&sysparm_stack=incident_list.do?sysparm_query=active=true"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Troubleshooting and recommendation:

We were finally able to repro this issue. It is a bug in the team's scope and doesn't repro in the personal scope. An easy way to unblock you would be to add in the `potentialAction` section an `@id` field like so:

```
"potentialAction": [
{
"@id":"1",
"@type": "OpenUri",
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stands out as a bug in your code or problem with your configuration. Linking to the GitHub issue where it is being investigated/troubleshot:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/issues/208